# Swift: Push Objects under the Label according to the number of lines

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextfield, material-design

I'm trying to make the same behavior of the Material design textfield with a custom textfield. 
I created a class that inherits from textfield and every thing is working fine. The only problem is in one scenario. when I have an object under the textfield, and i add the error label under the text field. the error label might be more than one line. so it overlays the object under the textfield. However, in the material design library, the objects under the textfield are automatically pushed down according ton the number of lines of the error label.

here is my custom textfield code:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import  RxCocoa

class FloatingTextField2: UITextField {

var placeholderLabel: UILabel!
var line: UIView!
var errorLabel: UILabel!

let bag = DisposeBag()
var activeColor = Constants.colorBlue
var inActiveColor = UIColor(red: 84/255.0, green: 110/255.0, blue: 122/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
var errorColorFull =  UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 103/255.0, blue: 103/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
//var errorColorParcial =  UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 103/255.0, blue: 103/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

private var lineYPosition: CGFloat!
private var lineXPosition: CGFloat!
private var lineWidth: CGFloat!
private var lineHeight: CGFloat!

private var errorLabelYPosition: CGFloat!
private var errorLabelXPosition: CGFloat!
private var errorLabelWidth: CGFloat!
private var errorLabelHeight: CGFloat!

var maxFontSize: CGFloat = 14
var minFontSize: CGFloat = 11

let errorLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 12)

var animationDuration = 0.35

var placeholderText: String = "" {
    didSet {
        if placeholderLabel != nil {
            placeholderLabel.text = placeholderText
        }
    }
}

var isTextEntrySecured: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        self.isSecureTextEntry = isTextEntrySecured
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    //setUpUI()

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    setUpUI()
}

func setUpUI() {
    if placeholderLabel == nil {

        placeholderLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: 20))
        self.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
        self.borderStyle = .none
        placeholderLabel.text = "Placeholder Preview"
        placeholderLabel.textColor = inActiveColor
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: maxFontSize)
        self.placeholderLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: maxFontSize)
        self.placeholder = ""
        self.textColor = .black

        setUpTextField()

    }

    if line == nil {
        lineYPosition = self.frame.height
        lineXPosition = -16
        lineWidth = self.frame.width + 32
        lineHeight = 1
        line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: lineXPosition, y: lineYPosition, width: lineWidth, height: lineHeight))
        self.addSubview(line)
        line.backgroundColor = inActiveColor
    }

    if errorLabel == nil {
        errorLabelYPosition = lineYPosition + 8
        errorLabelXPosition = 0
        errorLabelWidth = self.frame.width
        errorLabelHeight = calculateErrorLabelHeight(text: "")
        errorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: errorLabelYPosition, width: errorLabelWidth, height: errorLabelHeight))
        self.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        errorLabel.textColor = errorColorFull
        errorLabel.text = ""
        errorLabel.font = errorLabelFont
        sizeToFit()
    }

}


func setUpTextField(){
    self.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin).subscribe(onNext: { (next) in
        if self.text?.isEmpty ?? false {
            self.animatePlaceholderUp()
        }
    }).disposed(by: bag)

    self.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd).subscribe(onNext: { (next) in
        if self.text?.isEmpty ?? false {
            self.animatePlaceholderCenter()
        }
    }).disposed(by: bag)
}

func setErrorText(_ error: String?, errorAccessibilityValue: String?) {
    if let errorText = error {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        errorLabelHeight = calculateErrorLabelHeight(text: errorText)
        self.errorLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: errorLabelYPosition, width: errorLabelWidth, height: errorLabelHeight)
        self.errorLabel.text = errorText
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
        self.line.backgroundColor = errorColorFull
    }else{
        self.errorLabel.text = ""
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = true
    }

    errorLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = errorAccessibilityValue ?? "textinput_error"
}

func animatePlaceholderUp(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
        self.line.frame.size.height = 2
        self.line.backgroundColor = self.activeColor

        self.placeholderLabel.font = self.placeholderLabel.font.withSize(self.minFontSize)
        self.placeholderLabel.textColor = self.activeColor
        self.placeholderLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.frame.height/2 + 8) * -1, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (done) in

    }
}

func animatePlaceholderCenter(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
        self.line.frame.size.height = 1
        self.line.backgroundColor = self.inActiveColor

        self.placeholderLabel.font = self.placeholderLabel.font.withSize(self.maxFontSize)
        self.placeholderLabel.textColor = self.inActiveColor
        self.placeholderLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (done) in

    }
}

func calculateErrorLabelHeight(text:String) -> CGFloat{
    let font = errorLabelFont
    let width = self.frame.width
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I could not find anything on stack overflow or google related to my problem.

Comment: Try to add some visuals so it will be easier to understand what you mean

Comment: Couple things... 1) You *really* should use auto-layout / constraints rather than explicit frames. 2) You are adding subviews (`placeholderLabel`, `line` and `errorLabel` and positioning them ***outside*** the bounds of the text field. That means the text field frame will not change. Most likely, that is why your error label does not "push objects down." To get that functionality, your custom text field needs to be a `UIView` subclass, which *contains* a text field, placeholder label, line view and error label.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for comment! regarding point 1, still if i used constraints to position the objects of my component, I still didn't solve the problem of the whole component with the objects around. Regarding your second point, that was my first strategy but adding uiView to the storyboard will oblige me to give it a specific height. this will lead to a new problem which is that the errorLabel will not be able to expand for more than a specific number of lines

Comment: No, you do not have to give the view a *"specific height"*. That's part of auto-layout and constraints. When done correctly, the *contents* of the `UIView` (its subviews) can define the height of the view. Have you seen a multi-line label in a table view cell? That's exactly how that works.

Comment: Maybe You can help me in this, check this xib file that I created (forget about the question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855909/ios-animating-placeholder-like-material-design-textfield-placeholder/59855976?noredirect=1#comment105844243_59855976. 
After I created this xib file with the class, In the storyboard I'm assigning every view to this class. In this case the view in the storyboard can't determine its size from the content, cause the content is in a separate xib file. and i can't add the content to the storyboard because I'm reusing it in multiple controllers

Comment: @mahdi - edit that question and include the source of your xib file ... (in Xcode, right-click on it and select `Open As -> Source Code`)

Comment: @DonMag please check the question now. I have added what u asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

- You'll be much better off using constraints rather than explicit frames
- Adding subviews to a `UITextField` will show them outside the Bounds of the field, meaning they won't affect the frame (and thus the constraints)
- If the constraints are set properly, they will control the "containing view" height

The key to getting your "error" label to expand the view is to apply multiple vertical constraints, and activate / deactivate as needed.

Here is a complete example of a custom `UIView` which contains a text field, a placeholder label and an error label. The example view controller includes "demo" buttons to show the capabilities.

I suggest you add this code and try it out. If it suits your needs, there are plenty of comments in it that you should be able to tweak fonts, spacing, etc to your liking.

Or, it should at least give you some ideas of how to set up your own.

---

**FloatingTextFieldView - UIView subclass**

```
class FloatingTextFieldView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var placeHolderTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var placeHolderCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var placeHolderLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var lineHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var errorLabelBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var activeColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue
    var inActiveColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 84/255.0, green: 110/255.0, blue: 122/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
    var errorColorFull: UIColor =  UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 103/255.0, blue: 103/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    var animationDuration = 0.35

    var maxFontSize: CGFloat = 14
    var minFontSize: CGFloat = 11

    let errorLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 12)

    let placeholderLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Default Placeholder"
        v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return v
    }()

    let line: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return v
    }()

    let errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "Default Error"
        v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return v
    }()

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let v = UITextField()
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = .white

        [textField, line, placeholderLabel, errorLabel].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview($0)
        }

        // place holder label gets 2 vertical constraints
        //      top of view
        //      centerY to text field
        placeHolderTopConstraint = placeholderLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        placeHolderCenterYConstraint = placeholderLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)

        // place holder leading constraint is 16-pts (when centered on text field)
        //  when animated above text field, we'll change the constant to 0
        placeHolderLeadingConstraint = placeholderLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0)

        // error label bottom constrained to bottom of view
        //  will be activated when shown, deactivated when hidden
        errorLabelBottomConstraint = errorLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)

        // line height constraint constant changes between 1 and 2 (inactive / active)
        lineHeightConstraint = line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // text field top 16-pts from top of view
            // leading and trailing = 0
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // text field height = 24
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0),

            // text field bottom is AT LEAST 4 pts
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),

            // line view top is 2-pts below text field bottom
            // leading and trailing = 0
            line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            line.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            line.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // error label top is 4-pts from text field bottom
            // leading and trailing = 0
            errorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            errorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            errorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            placeHolderCenterYConstraint,
            placeHolderLeadingConstraint,
            lineHeightConstraint,

        ])

        // I'm not using Rx, so set the delegate
        textField.delegate = self

        textField.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: maxFontSize)
        textField.textColor = .black

        placeholderLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: maxFontSize)
        placeholderLabel.textColor = inActiveColor

        line.backgroundColor = inActiveColor

        errorLabel.textColor = errorColorFull
        errorLabel.font = errorLabelFont

    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? false {
            self.animatePlaceholderUp()
        }

    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? false {
            self.animatePlaceholderCenter()
        }

    }

    func animatePlaceholderUp() -> Void {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
            // increase line height
            self.lineHeightConstraint.constant = 2.0
            // set line to activeColor
            self.line.backgroundColor = self.activeColor

            // set placeholder label font and color
            self.placeholderLabel.font = self.placeholderLabel.font.withSize(self.minFontSize)
            self.placeholderLabel.textColor = self.activeColor

            // deactivate placeholder label CenterY constraint
            self.placeHolderCenterYConstraint.isActive = false
            // activate placeholder label Top constraint
            self.placeHolderTopConstraint.isActive = true
            // move placeholder label leading to 0
            self.placeHolderLeadingConstraint.constant = 0

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (done) in

        }

    }

    func animatePlaceholderCenter() -> Void {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
            // decrease line height
            self.lineHeightConstraint.constant = 1.0
            // set line to inactiveColor
            self.line.backgroundColor = self.inActiveColor

            // set placeholder label font and color
            self.placeholderLabel.font = self.placeholderLabel.font.withSize(self.maxFontSize)
            self.placeholderLabel.textColor = self.inActiveColor

            // deactivate placeholder label Top constraint
            self.placeHolderTopConstraint.isActive = false
            // activate placeholder label CenterY constraint
            self.placeHolderCenterYConstraint.isActive = true
            // move placeholder label leading to 16
            self.placeHolderLeadingConstraint.constant = 16

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (done) in

        }

    }

    func setErrorText(_ error: String?, errorAccessibilityValue: String?, endEditing: Bool) {
        if let errorText = error {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {

                self.errorLabel.text = errorText
                self.line.backgroundColor = self.errorColorFull
                self.errorLabel.isHidden = false

                // activate error label Bottom constraint
                self.errorLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = true

            }) { (done) in
                if endEditing {
                    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        }else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {

                self.errorLabel.text = ""
                self.line.backgroundColor = self.inActiveColor
                self.errorLabel.isHidden = true

                // deactivate error label Bottom constraint
                self.errorLabelBottomConstraint.isActive = false

            }) { (done) in
                if endEditing {
                    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        }

        errorLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = errorAccessibilityValue ?? "textinput_error"
    }

    // func to set / clear element background colors
    // to make it easy to see the frames
    func showHideFrames(show b: Bool) -> Void {
        if b {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            placeholderLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
            errorLabel.backgroundColor = .green
            textField.backgroundColor = .yellow
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .white
            [placeholderLabel, errorLabel, textField].forEach {
                $0.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

**DemoFLoatingTextViewController**

```
class DemoFLoatingTextViewController: UIViewController {

    // FloatingTextFieldView
    let sampleFTF: FloatingTextFieldView = {
        let v = FloatingTextFieldView()
        return v
    }()

    // a label to constrain below the FloatingTextFieldView
    //  so we can see it gets "pushed down"
    let demoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "This is a label outside the Floating Text Field. As you will see, it gets \"pushed down\" when the error label is shown."
        v.backgroundColor = .brown
        v.textColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    // buttons to Demo the functionality
    let btnA: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("End Editing", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let btnB: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Set Error", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let btnC: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Clear Error", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let btnD: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Set & End", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let btnE: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Clear & End", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let btnF: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Show Frames", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let btnG: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton(type: .system)
        b.setTitle("Hide Frames", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return b
    }()

    let errorMessages: [String] = [
        "Simple Error",
        "This will end up being a Multiline Error message. It is long enough to cause word wrapping."
    ]

    var errorCount: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add Demo buttons
        let btnStack = UIStackView()
        btnStack.axis = .vertical
        btnStack.spacing = 6
        btnStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        [[btnA], [btnB, btnC], [btnD, btnE], [btnF, btnG]].forEach { btns in
            let sv = UIStackView()
            sv.distribution = .fillEqually
            sv.spacing = 12
            sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            btns.forEach {
                sv.addArrangedSubview($0)
            }

            btnStack.addArrangedSubview(sv)
        }

        view.addSubview(btnStack)

        // add FloatingTextFieldView and demo label
        view.addSubview(sampleFTF)
        view.addSubview(demoLabel)

        sampleFTF.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        demoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // buttons stack Top = 20, centerX, width = 80% of view width
            btnStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            btnStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),

            // FloatingTextFieldView Top = 40-pts below buttons stack
            sampleFTF.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            // FloatingTextFieldView Leading = 60-pts
            sampleFTF.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            // FloatingTextFieldView width = 240
            sampleFTF.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),

            // Note: we are not setting the FloatingTextFieldView Height!

            // constrain demo label Top = 8-pts below FloatingTextFieldView bottom
            demoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleFTF.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            // Leading = FloatingTextFieldView Leading
            demoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleFTF.leadingAnchor),
            // Width = 200
            demoLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),

        ])

        // add touchUpInside targets for demo buttons
        btnA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(endEditing(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setError(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearError(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnD.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setAndEnd(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnE.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearAndEnd(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showFrames(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnG.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideFrames(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func endEditing(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func setError(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.setErrorText(errorMessages[errorCount % 2], errorAccessibilityValue: "", endEditing: false)
        errorCount += 1
    }

    @objc func clearError(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.setErrorText(nil, errorAccessibilityValue: "", endEditing: false)
    }

    @objc func setAndEnd(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.setErrorText(errorMessages[errorCount % 2], errorAccessibilityValue: "", endEditing: true)
        errorCount += 1
    }

    @objc func clearAndEnd(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.setErrorText(nil, errorAccessibilityValue: "", endEditing: true)
    }

    @objc func showFrames(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.showHideFrames(show: true)
    }

    @objc func hideFrames(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        sampleFTF.showHideFrames(show: false)
    }

}
```

---

**Example results:**

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: simple and straight forward, Thanks!

Comment: But don't you think that `errorLabelBottomConstraint` should be always active?

Comment: @mahdi - give it a try and see what happens.